# What is the strategy for working with different types of Monad Transformers?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskell-persistent

I'm trying to implement a simple web server that interacts with some other API and stores the response after doing some processing.

To encapsulate the possibility of failure (empty response, incorrect request, etc) I am using `ExceptT` as following:

```
getExample
  :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader ApplicationConfig m)
  => ExceptT ApplicationError m [Example]
getExample = do

  partOfReq <- asks requestForSometing

  fn1 =<< fn2 partOfReq
```

and I have another function that stores the response in a database using [insertMany_](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.0/persistent-2.10.5.2/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:insertMany_) from Persistent.

```
storeExample
  :: ( MonadIO m
     , PersistStoreWrite backend
     , PersistEntityBackend Example ~ BaseBackend backend
     )
  => [Example]
  -> ReaderT backend m ()
storeExample = insertMany_
```

Now I want to write a function

```
getResponseAndStore = ... {- A combination of getExample and storeExample -}
```

that will do both of these things and bubble up `ApplicationConfig` and `PersistEntityBackend` requirements to the top where the user could provide them in a bundle.

Would that be possible?

If so - What would the strategy/implementation be?

If no - What changes shall I consider?

Edit: This is what I'm doing currently.

```
getResponseAndStore
  :: ( MonadIO m
     , MonadReader ApplicationConfig m
     , PersistStoreWrite backend
     , PersistEntityBackend Example ~ BaseBackend backend
     )
  => ReaderT backend (ExceptT ApplicationError m) ()
getResponseAndStore = storeExample =<< lift getExample
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make a function that does just want I want to. The secret sauce was using [withPostgresqlConn](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.0/persistent-postgresql-2.10.1.2/Database-Persist-Postgresql.html#v:withPostgresqlConn).

```
process :: ReaderT ApplicationConfig IO (Either ApplicationError ())
process = do

  appConfig <- ask
  connStr   <- asks connectionString

  runStdoutLoggingT
    $ withPostgresqlConn connStr
    $ flip ($) appConfig
    . runReaderT
    . runExceptT
    . runReaderT getResponseAndStore
```

Comment: Note: if I'm not mistaken, you can replace `flip ($)` with `(&)`

Answer (score 0):

can't you use the `MonadError` syntax instead?

```
getExample
  :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader ApplicationConfig m, MonadError ApplicationError m)
  => [Example]
getExample = -- ...

getResponseAndStore :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader ApplicationConfig m, PersistStoreWrite backend, PersistEntityBackend Example ~ BaseBackend backend, MonadError ApplicationError m) => -- etc.
```

Comment: I just looked into it and found this message at the top `Deprecated: Use Control.Monad.Except instead`.

Comment: In `Control.Monad.Error`, yes. The recommended module is `Control.Monad.Except`, but the typeclass name remains the same: `MonadError`

Comment: Ah thank you for clarifying, I'm really unfamiliar with `mtl `.

Comment: Also if you wouldn't mind, could you elaborate on what the function body of `getResponseAndStore` should be?